# ng-option dropdown list of objects not setting ng-option when selected = true

Tags: angularjs

I have an Object Student `{id,name, subject:{id,name}}`

I want to prepopulate value of student when clicked on edit student. I want to show subjects in drop down list with selected value as student's assigned subject.

For example:
I have a student with 
`{id:1,
name:abc,
subject:{id:2,name:maths}}`

And I have a subject list as
`{id:1,name:english,
id:2,name:maths,
id:3,name:computers}`

```
select.form-control(name="subject", id="subject", ng-required="true", ng-model="student.subject", ng-options="subject.name for subject in subjects")
  option( value="", ng-selected="true") --choose subject--
```

I am using jade as the template and AngularJs (version 1.0.7)

Comment: Please try to provide a fiddle to demonstrate your problem

Comment: What is this `select.form-control` code?  Is that back-end code for generating the HTML?

Comment: Nevermind.  I see that this is a Jade template syntax.  I think you will get better answers if you can remove Jade from your question and stick with plain HTML.

Answer (score 0):

The data structure doesn't make sense, you need a list of objects (JSON) like this

```
$scope.subjects = [{
    id: 1,
    name: 'english'
}, {
    id: 2,
    name: 'maths'
}, {
    id: 3,
    name: 'computers'
}]
```